# classes and Interfaces in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I am in the beginning of learning TypeScript. I come from a strongly-typed language (c#) and have some knowledge in JS.

Quite at the beginning I fell over the following example:

```
class Student {
    fullName: string;
    constructor(public firstName, public middleInitial, public lastName) {
        this.fullName = firstName + " " + middleInitial + " " + lastName;
    }
}

interface Person {
    firstName: string;
    lastName: string;
}

function greeter(person : Person) {
    return "Hello, " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}

var user = new Student("Jane", "M.", "User");

document.body.innerHTML = greeter(user);
```

Now I am a bit confused. I would expect something like `Student:Person` (c#) or `Student implements Person` (Java)
So: Why does `greeter()` accept an object of class "`Student`"? I did not see any clue that "`Student`" implements "`Person`".

is it just about the property names?
So if I add another class

```
class Teacher {
  salaray:int,
  firstName:string,
  lastName:string
}
```

an object of that class would also be a valid parameter for `greeter()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are right about your assumption. You can see the code that typescript transpiles into. The code that you posted (I changed the last line to an alert) looks like this

```
var Student = (function () {
    function Student(firstName, middleInitial, lastName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.middleInitial = middleInitial;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.fullName = firstName + " " + middleInitial + " " + lastName;
    }
    return Student;
}());

function greeter(person) {
    return "Hello, " + person.firstName + " " + person.lastName;
}

var user = new Student("Jane", "M.", "User");
alert(greeter(user));
```

Once the typescript is transpiled to javascript, all that knowledge of those interfaces and classes is lost. You can see that from the transpiled example above. In this example, it makes sense that it would run correctly because the incoming variable `person` actually does have the properties that the method is accessing. So Typescript can see that the transpiled version of your code actually does make sense and will not complain about it.

Comment: The explanation make sense, though from this code, the argument person comes from "nowehere"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you're correct, the compiler checks whether or not the object that is passed to `greeter` satisfies the `Person` interface, and since the `Student` class contains all of the needed properties then the compiler is happy about it.

And yes, you can do this:

```
class Teacher {
    salaray: number;
    firstName:string;
    lastName:string;
}

document.body.innerHTML = greeter(new Teacher());
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=class%20Student%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20fullName%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20firstName%2C%20public%20middleInitial%2C%20public%20lastName)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20this.fullName%20%3D%20firstName%20%2B%20%22%20%22%20%2B%20middleInitial%20%2B%20%22%20%22%20%2B%20lastName%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Person%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20firstName%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20lastName%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20greeter(person%20%3A%20Person)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20%22Hello%2C%20%22%20%2B%20person.firstName%20%2B%20%22%20%22%20%2B%20person.lastName%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20user%20%3D%20new%20Student(%22Jane%22%2C%20%22M.%22%2C%20%22User%22)%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aclass%20Teacher%20%7B%0D%0A%09salaray%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%09firstName%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%09lastName%3Astring%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Adocument.body.innerHTML%20%3D%20greeter(new%20Teacher())%3B))

Comment: Ok. It was a 50/50 decision what answer to accept. Thx nonetheless. :)